# Creating and Uploading Append Blobs to store in Azure Container

Tags: c#, azure, append, azure-container-service

I am trying to upload a new append blob file to a container every time a message comes in from a service bus. I do not want to append to the blob that is already there. I want to create a whole new append blob and add it at the end.

Is this possible?

I was looking at this article but couldn't quiet understand what they meant when they got to the content part: https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/javascript/azure-storage-blob/12.1.1/classes/appendblobclient.html#appendblock

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
public static async void StoreToBlob(Services service)
    {
        //Serealize Object 
        var sender = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(service);

        // Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

        // Create the container and return a container client object
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.  
        await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        //Reference to blob
        AppendBlobClient appendBlobClient = containerClient.GetAppendBlobClient("services" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".json");

        // Create the blob. 
        appendBlobClient.Create();

        await appendBlobClient.AppendBlock(sender, sender.Length); //here is where I am having an issue
    }
```

Comment: What are the issues you're facing?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to learn how to create a json file, add an serialize object to it then add it to my container. When I get to the AppendBlock part it is asking me for a stream, however, I dont have a file.

Comment: Do i need to create one first then add it ? @Gaurav Mantri

Comment: @GauravMantri ^

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like the following (not tested code):

```
byte[] blockContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sender);
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(blockContent))
{
    appendBlobClient.AppendBlock(ms, blockContent.Length);
}
```

Essentially we're converting the string to byte array, creating a stream out of it and then uploading that stream.

Comment: Thanks. I plugged that code in and had to take out the Length part b/c the method wanted bytes and not length. Then got rid of the "await" since the system said I didnt need it.

Comment: After running though. My code stopped at the line here:

"appendBlobClient.Create();"

 and said the file does not exist. Im trying to figure out why are they saying it doesnt exist if that the one that I am trying to create.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Awesome. I am glad to hear that.